# Running a .post() for each element using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, .post

I'm having trouble running a jQuery `.post` over each element in my table. The following is my code

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="load_img"></td>
        <td class="load_img"></td>
        <td class="load_img"></td>
        <td class="load_img"></td>
        <td class="load_img"></td>
        <td class="load_img"></td>
        <td class="load_img"></td>
        <td class="load_img"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

javascript

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("td.load_ads").html("<img src='/classified_ads4free/images/icons/ajax-loader.gif'>");
     $("td.load_ads").each(function(){
       var loading=$(this);

       $.post('/classified_ads4free/self_coded_helpers/jpost_get_ads.php',function(data)
       {
          loading.html(data);
       });
     });
    });
```

.POST PHP script

```
 <?php
   $index=rand(0,10);
   echo $index;
 ?>
```

So what I'm trying to do here is to have each `<td>` in my table load a random number but my problem now is that all the `<td>`'s loaded the same random number. Instead of each one having a random number from 0-10.

(this is just for illustration, I know its possible to generate a random number using jquery but the purpose why I need to do a `.post` is because I will be running queries to get load images within these table elements.)

Comment: Have you tried to add [`srand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php) before `rand()` to re-initialize `rand()` on each call?

Comment: @j0k, calling `srand` by hand has not been needed since *4.2.0*.  It's always initialized on first call now.  Further, manually seeding it can [lead to very, very bad results](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/76241/19717).

Comment: @Charles oh interesting, thanks

Comment: **class="load_img"** in the markup and **$("td.load_ads").html** and **$("td.load_ads").each(** in the jquery. Have you considered it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the help. Got it solved. What i did was to create an artificial variable index. Then have the index increment everytime i launch the .post with a new loop. Don't know why but it kind of work in the way i would like it to operate. My new javascript code as follows incase anybody needs it.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("td.load_ads").each(function(){
        var loading=$(this);
        var index=0;
        $(this).html("<img src='/classified_ads4free/images/icons/ajax-loader.gif'>");
        $.post('/classified_ads4free/self_coded_helpers/jpost_get_ads.php',{index:index},function(data){
            loading.html(data);
            index=index+1;
        });
    });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a problem of cache.
As your request is always the same, the browser send only one time the request.
Solutions are:

1/ add a html headerin your php script to not cache the answer:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");  
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

2/ add a random parameter in the request

Answer (score 0):

It seem's to be a caching problem.

The simplest workaround is, to add a random number to the url.

```
var d = new Date();

$.post( '/classified_ads4free/self_coded_helpers/jpost_get_ads.php'
        + '?_=' + d.getTime()
        + '&_=' + Math.random(),
        function( data ) { /* stuff */ }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("td.load_ads").html("<img src='/classified_ads4free/images/icons/ajax-loader.gif'>");
     $.post('/classified_ads4free/self_coded_helpers/jpost_get_ads.php',function(data){
       $.each($("td.load_ads"), function(){
         var loading=$(this);   
         loading.html(data);
       });
     });
  });
```

`I think you should iterate in the success function.`

Comment: Hi. No. As my random number is being generated in the script itself, I need the .post to be generated for every time the function re-loops and repeats itself.

Comment: **echo $index;** is it generating 10 random numbers or just one per call?